# Is there any cam splitter for ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, webcam

I've been searching for a long time now online and decided to ask. Is there any webcam splitter for ubuntu? a prog that lets you use your webcam on more than one application at the same time...i can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

## **[Webcam Studio](http://www.ws4gl.org/)**

Allow you to use the virtual webcam provided during the program execution in order to be able to use it for several applications which includes but not limits only to: Skype, Google+ and other flash based video-chat web services (like http://ubiqq.com).

In the next screenshot I am using **Webcam Studio** in order to use my webcam (with a pre-recorded video) and share it through 2 web services: Google+ and Ubiqq.com

[image]

Please note that depending on the service, the image can be shown to you mirrored. Additionally, you may experience some lag when using the cam for more than 1 service at once.

It is hungry in resources as you can see in my system monitor panel's applet, I am using the majority of my 4GB RAM (the green square) when doing this, which lessen when I close both the application and the browser and a huge amount of my Core2quad microprocessor, which also lessen after closing everything.

I don't usually use this service for more than a service but your question encouraged me to run a test, which -in my case- was successfully.

Even if this doesn't solve your question, I hope this give you a clue and you find a solution soon.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try it and let you know if it worked out.

Comment: how do i can install the  Webcam Studio ?

Comment: Easy installation instructions are provided here: http://www.ws4gl.org/download/installing-on-ubuntu, a direct link to download the .deb installation file is right here: http://webcamstudio.googlecode.com/files/webcamstudio_0.57beta4_all.deb, simply download this file and run it by opening the file. The old repository seems not to be available any longer so it is suggested to use the .deb instead. Good luck!